# NodeJS/express: server hanged after start running for a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I made my service with express and webpack and it worked well at the beginning. The weird thing is that after a while the service(server) will hang. As the screenshot displays, no message code received.[(server message screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU0rk.png)
And this happens again and again.

My app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var generals = require('./routes/generals');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/generals', generals);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The here is the route file: generals.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();
var pool = require('./connections');

router.get('/dropDownValue/', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query("select * from drop_down_value order by id desc", function(err, rows) {
            if (!err && rows.length > 0) {
                res.json(rows);
            } else {
                res.json([]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the connections file:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx'
});

exports.getConnection = function (callback) {
    pool.getConnection(callback);
};
```

Comment: Add support of unhandled rejection (for promise) and uncaught exception (for try catch) in your code and tell us if you see something new in your logs when the server hangs

Comment: The 304 isn't the issue (it's Express telling your browser that the cached version of a file is still up-to-date), it's the requests to `/generals/dropDownValue` that start failing. We have no idea why, because you're not showing its code. Also, `pool` isn't a global, as opposed to what the comment states.

Comment: @robertklep I've updated the code and remove the global pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `pool.getConnection()`, once you're done with the connection (i.e. the query has finished), you need to release the connection back to the pool again:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query("select * from drop_down_value order by id desc", function(err, rows) {

        connection.release(); // <- this

        if (!err && rows.length > 0) {
            res.json(rows);
        } else {
            res.json([]);
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, once you have performed 10 queries, there are no more connections available in the pool and it will start waiting (indefinitely) for connections to be released, hanging the requests.